# Action Launcher can't load actions

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-app-builder

I've set up an action launcher deployment and added the action launcher component to a record page, but every time I click to search for an action, I get the error message: "We couldn't load the actions. Reload Action Launcher and try again." What I am missing here?[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solve?

Comment: I haven’t solved it yet